# Django SQLITE3 BASE_DIR not working when moving machines

Tags: python, django, sqlite

So I have the following code which specifies the path of where my db file is located on my system.

It works flawlessly on the computer which I have created my django project in. However, when I move the project to a different machine, it does not find the db.sqlite3 file and instead creates a new one in the root directory of that machine, so I have to create a DB_DIR and manually specify the path and cannot use BASE_DIR for the database connection.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: for sqlite3 db, you can migrate to create a new db in other machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Django 3):

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With sqlite, the NAME is just a name. The file is always placed in the BASE_DIR and any path elements included in the name are ignored.

See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77938247/why-is-this-local-django-databases-configuration-not-honored-in-django-5-0-1) on this for a little more detail.