# Why is this local django DATABASES configuration not honored in django 5.0.1?

Tags: django

I'm using a local.py settings inclusion so the devs can use sqlite3 and deployed sites can use things like postgres. This is the local_py_example.py (using /tmp just for this repro):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/tmp/db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

The settings file imports this thus:

```
import os
import sys

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from utilities.find_base_dir import find_base_dir

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = find_base_dir()

sys.path.insert(0, f"{BASE_DIR.parent}")  # will look for local.py in the parent directory
try:
    # noinspection PyPackageRequirements,PyUnresolvedReferences
    from local import *
except ImportError:
    from club_site.settings.local_py_example import *

sys.path.pop(0)

... (no DATABASES declared in settings (ONLY IN local.py))
print(f"sqlite: {DATABASES['default']['NAME']}")  # at end just for debugging this
```

An e.g. 'django migrate' creates the database at the wrong location (in the BASE_DIR) in spite of the print statement at the end of the settings showing the correct location (/tmp/db.sqlite3).

Comment: Seems that the name for sqlite in DATABASES ignores any path and just puts it in the BASE_DIR. This is not related to the local.py stuff as I initially suspected.

Comment: Closer examination suggests that the name for sqlite3 strips the path information and always creates the resulting file 'name' in the django BASE_DIR.

This rarely matters because sqlite3 is not for production use and .gitignore can ignore the database when it is put in the BASE_DIR.

Reviewing the django source, the name/path is confounded so putting in the path while it is not honored looks likely to break any test relying upon copying the sqlite3 file as a test db.